# WordPress Search return wrong results

Tags: plugins, search

i limit the search in my WP blog to be within post only by adding this line

```
<?php if (is_search() && ($post->post_type=='page')) continue; ?>
```

So any results from static pages will be excluded , that fine but i have a problem 
if i have a post and it has the below content

> Test POST
>
> [video width="320" height="240"
>   mp4="http://localhost/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/a1.mp4"
>   poster="1.jpg"][/video]

and if i try to search by this keyword " post "
it return this post which has video tag and "**post**er" attribute , which not make sense 
so how i can exclude the attribute of media tags in search results .

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that WordPress searches for matches using `LIKE %post%`, meaning that any post (that is Post, Page or custom post type object) that contains `post` in it's title or **content** is found.

You can alter this default behaviour by using the [`posts_where`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) action hook.

```
add_action( 'posts_where', 'my_alter_search_where' );
function my_alter_search_where( $where ){

    global $wpdb;

    if (is_search()) :

        $where.= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_content NOT LIKE '%poster=%'";

    endif;

}
```

The only caviat here is that if your post content contains both `%post` and `%poster="%` as two seperate occurances, it will not be included.  There are ways around this, but I'd need to know more about your query, so if this answere is acceptable I'd suggest posting that as a seperate question.